# os.environ with nonexistent keys/environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables

For a python program, I am using `os.environ()` to get environment variables with a certain key. However, I would like to be able do something if the key is nonexistent in the environment, instead of throwing a `KeyError`.

I've looked up a few solutions, but `os.environ.get()` and `os.getenv()` seem to act differently than how I expect. Is there any way to use `os.environ()` and still work around nonexistent environment variables?

Comment: `os.environ.get(keyname, value_if_not_there)` is what I would have recommended... can you explain how it is acting differently than you expect?  (Of course, another option would be to put the whole shebang in a try/except block and just catch the KeyError and act accordingly, but it's unlikely to result in code as nice as .get ... )

Comment: Also note that `os.environ` isn't a function so you shouldn't be calling it (although I suspect that you aren't or you wouldn't be getting a `KeyError`).

Comment: My issue was that I was calling os.environ.get[] instead of os.environ.get(), so now the behavior is how I expect. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

```
os.environ.get("foo")
```

returns `None` if "foo" is not found.

You can also use

```
if "foo" in os.environ:
```